# Which type of Visual Studio project for new app?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I need to develop a new internal app for our business.  It will run on about 50 computers -- laptops (or tablets?) installed in cars much like police have.  The device will connect to a couple of things (scale, GPS antenna) via USB, so I thing that rules ASP.NET Web Application.

So as a Microsoft/Visual Studio developer, my question is:

A) Windows Forms Application
B) WPF Application
C) Windows Store Application
D) Other?

We have existing Windows Forms Applications, and know that technology well.. but have heard that Microsoft is moving away from WinForms in favor or, e.g., the other choices listed (true?).

Any guidance?  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should definetely go WPF if the machines can support it (tablets will have full windows version not RT). But if tablets will be RT then you need to go windows store app for windows 8.

WPF is a modern framework which enables developer to achieve UX and GUI more easily and in structured way compared to WinForms. It takes a day or so to get used when moving from WinForms to WPF but after that you will not want to remember those old OnPaint methods and so on.

Answer (score 2):

WinForms is a very very old technology and I doubt if Microsoft still provides support for it. Plus it is a pain to develop in so I would recommend against it.

If you are going to use Laptops, you can use WPF for development.

However if you are going to install tablets which run only Windows RT and not a full version of Windows then you should develop a Windows Store app.